# Загрузить картинку и получить на нее ссылку piccy.info

Tags: java, изображения, загрузка

Можно как-то загрузить картинку на piccy.info и получить на нее ссылку?

или может есть какой опробованный способ, чтобы загрузить картинку на какой-нибудь сайт-хостинг и получить на нее прямую ссылку, в автоматическом режиме?

Answer (score 0):

В общем то алгоритм действий прост и одинаков для любого сайта. Заходите на нужный сайт, смотрите все логи и изучаете порядок действий... Далее всё это воспроизводите в своей программе и т.о. сделаете загрузку картинки с получением на неё ссылки.